# Scala syntax in nested functions

Tags: scala, syntax

This question is mainly about syntax problems

I have a program to count the number of parentheses to see if they match, so there must be an equal amount of "(" and ")", without a ")" preceding a "("

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  if (chars.isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException

  def helper(chars: List[Char], num: Int = 0, check: Int = 1): (Int, Int) = {
    if (num < 0) check = 0
    if (chars.head == "(") return helper(chars.tail, num + 1)
    if (chars.head == ")") return helper(chars.tail, num - 1)
    else return(chars.tail, num)
  }

  if (num == 0 && check == 1) return true
  else return false
}
```

This is what I am trying to do :

1. Define a function that returns a `Boolean` true of false based upon a list
2. If the list is empty, then return that nothing is there
3. Define a helper function that returns two integers check and `num` that can be used as conditionals to determine if the parentheses match
4. If `num` is less that zero, it means that there was a right parenthesis before a left one, that is unacceptable, check has been changed to 0
5. If the character value in the head is a left parenthesis, I call the helper function with the `num` value increased by one
6. If the character value in the head is a right parenthesis, I call the helper function with the `num` value decreased by one
7. If the character value in the head is neither a right parenthesis nor a left, I call the helper function with the `num` value decreased by one

   The point of this function is to return a `num` and check variable to return a boolean of the function that it is nested in
8. In the outer function, I want to determine if there was a right parenthesis before a left one (`check == 0`), or they did not match (`num != 1`)

What syntax changes should I make?  I like this way of logically thinking about things, so please don't try to change my logic, unless I am not embracing a functional style, and still thinking more procedurally.

Comment: why do you want to make syntax changes?

Comment: It's too many places to fix and you are saying do not change that complicated `logic` which is unnecessary to be so. you are not only denying    functional programming but scala itself.there are ton of useful staff though you don't want to get changed. go back the language you used to use.
Plus you didn't mention what the problem is. your code actually have both ploblems syntax one and logic one. how people can answer that?

Comment: What is the purpose of the value `check`? The way you are using it doesn't work and it's not clear what you want with this. You cannot re-assign a value to an argument value. The values `num` and `check` are not defined in the enclosing method. Also, you are not calling the `helper` method anywhere in the enclosing method.

Comment: The reason that I added a variable check was to set a value if a right parenthesis came before a left one, which is if num was less than 0, then check would be set at 0 instead of 1, and this means the List was not balanced.  The reason I typed the above steps is because this is how I was thinking about the process, if I am not using the benefits of functional programming, and Scala, then please tell me, and also tell me that I should think about this process in a different manner.  It is helpful if the process becomes intelligible to me.

Answer (score 0):

I made some small changes to make your code working:

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  if (chars.isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException

  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def helper(chars: List[Char], num: Int = 0): Boolean = chars match {
    case _ if num < 0 => false
    case head :: tail if head == '(' =>
      helper(tail, num + 1)
    case head :: tail if head == ')' =>
      helper(tail, num - 1)
    case head :: tail =>
      helper(tail, num)
    case Nil => num == 0
  }
  helper(chars)
}

balance("()()()()(".toList) //res0: Boolean = false
balance("(adsads)()()()sdfsdfsdf".toList) //res1: Boolean = true
balance("(()()()(asdasd))".toList) //res2: Boolean = true
balance("asdasd".toList) //res3: Boolean = true
balance("()()(()(".toList) //res4: Boolean = false
balance("".toList) // java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

or without pattern matching:

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  if (chars.isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException

  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def helper(chars: List[Char], num: Int = 0): Boolean = {
    if (num < 0)
      false
    else if(chars.isEmpty)
      num == 0
    else if(chars.head == '(')
      helper(chars.tail, num + 1)
    else if(chars.head == ')')
      helper(chars.tail, num - 1)
    else
      helper(chars.tail, num)
  }
  helper(chars)
}

balance("()()()()(".toList) //res0: Boolean = false
balance("(adsads)()()()sdfsdfsdf".toList) //res1: Boolean = true
balance("(()()()(asdasd))".toList) //res2: Boolean = true
balance("asdasd".toList) //res3: Boolean = true
balance("()()(()(".toList) //res4: Boolean = false
balance("".toList) // java.util.NoSuchElementException
```